# Restricting texbox to not accept number format as ("010")

Tags: c#, validation, textbox

In my program, I have texboxes which I type the grade of a student. But I want to restrict the user to not digit a number in format like 010 or 020. Also, if the user digits 1 and change to another textbox it autommaticaly changes this digited number (1) to 1,0.

I tried this, but when it enters the second condition, it gives me an error.

```
private void txt3Bimestre_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txt3Bimestre.Text[0].ToString().Equals("1") ||
        txt3Bimestre.Text[0].ToString().Equals("2") ||
        txt3Bimestre.Text[0].ToString().Equals("3") ||
        txt3Bimestre.Text[0].ToString().Equals("4") ||
        txt3Bimestre.Text[0].ToString().Equals("5") ||
        txt3Bimestre.Text[0].ToString().Equals("6") ||
        txt3Bimestre.Text[0].ToString().Equals("7") ||
        txt3Bimestre.Text[0].ToString().Equals("8") ||
        txt3Bimestre.Text[0].ToString().Equals("9"))
    {

        if (txt3Bimestre.Text[1].ToString().Equals(",") || txt3Bimestre.Text.Substring(0, 2) == "10")
        {
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Formato Inválido", "Alertaa", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        txt3Bimestre.Clear();
        txt3Bimestre.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show what you did

Comment: you are also new to the site and should read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're trying to force user to not input data as he/she wants on the textbox.

What I recommend u to to is to let user enter what he/she wants and, after leave the textbox or execute another event, test the data if it's the valid format or show the user an alert about his/her "mistake".

For example:

```
double value;

bool ok = double.TryParse(txt3Bimestre.Text, out value))

if (ok)
{
    txt3Bimestre.Text = value.ToString("0.00");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Formato Inválido", "Alerta", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    txt3Bimestre.Clear();
    txt3Bimestre.Focus();
}
```

If you have problems with , or . for decimals (culture related differences for decimals separator), look for CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.

Hope it helps.